# retrofit 2 delete method quest failure

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

HI got this method in my API interface

```
@DELETE("/posts/{id}") 
Call<Void> deletePost(@Path("id") int id);
```

but my method to call is facing a failure :

```
mAPIService.deletePost(id ).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            showResponse(response.body().toString());
            Log.i("TAG", "post deleted to API." + response.body().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Unable to submit post to API.");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you log with logging interceptors to check whats happening. Does you call require any headers?

Comment: is got me and null response

Comment: ok. you can test your call with postman. Also your base url should end with / and you need to change to `@DELETE("posts/{id}") `. Apart from that you can use Interceptors to log your requests https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Answer (score 0):

Use `Call<ResponseBody>`, not `Call<Void>`

Comment: I don't think it should matter for the OP

Comment: @AnkitSharma He's checking for status in response body. How response is stored into a void return?